# C++ Node.js - got error LNK 2001

Tags: c++, node.js, lnk2001

have problem with an unresolved extern.

the problem -> an header (myImpressiveHeaderFile.h) file tolds that he cannot find a symbol. But another file (holys_i.c) a c-file exists in this project and holds this symbols.

if i create a new win32-console-project (empty) and add these files (and a third file, with a main function and include the header file) it works perfectly.

BUT -> if i let node-gyp build the project (same files except main file xD that is a node spcefic file with v8.h and node.h - but included header file too) - i got errors (LNK 2001 see above).

it seems that the linker gots the c-file not or later if i create it with node-gyp? or does node-gyp not compile c-files? that cant be? or?

Do you have any ideas what i can do/test/check?

EDIT (add example):

**First Example (works)!**
*Header File (1)* (added sth like an extern var - name top.h)

`EXTERN_C const IID IID_IOPCServer;`

*C-File* (defined the var - name top_i.c)

```
MIDL_DEFINE_GUID(IID, IID_IOPCServer,0x39c13a4d,0x011e,0x11d0,0x96,0x75,0x00,0x20,0xaf,0xd8,0xad,0xb3);
```

*Another Header File (2)* (included Header File 1 - top.h - do nothing relevant - name stop.h)

*CPP File of Header File (2)* (included Header File 2 - used var - name stop.cpp)

```
hr = CoCreateInstance (clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER ,IID_IOPCServer, (void**)&m_IOPCServer);
```

*Main CPP File* (includes Header File 2 - dont used var - name test.cpp)
This Fule uses Functions of stop.cpp. Ans stop.cpp used the extern var.

When i add these file to a empty win32 console project - it works. ALL FINE!

**BUT** in other example

(same top.h, same top_i.c, same stop.h and same stop.cpp)
i let node-gyp build.

Binding Gyp:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "test",

      "sources": [ 


        "src/top.h",
        "src/top_i.c",

        "src/stop.h",
        "src/stop.cpp",

        "src/test.cpp"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

inside of test.cpp sth like this:

```
#include <node.h>
#include <v8.h>

#include "stop.h"

Handle<Value> Method(const Arguments& args) {
  HandleScope scope;

  return scope.Close(String::New("world"));
}

void init(Handle<Object> target) {
  NODE_SET_METHOD(target, "hello", Method);
}

NODE_MODULE(test, init);
```

**This** Example fails Oo

```
stop.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "IID_IOPCServer".
[D:\Dev\Workspaces\Nax\Github\node-test\build\test.vcxproj]
stop.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "IID_IOPCItemMgt".
[D:\Dev\Workspaces\Nax\Github\node-test\build\test.vcxproj]
stop.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "IID_IOPCSyncIO".
[D:\Dev\Workspaces\Nax\Github\node-test\build\test.vcxproj]
D:\Dev\Workspaces\Nax\Github\node-test\build\Release\test.node : fatal error LNK1
120: 3 unresolved externals [D:\Dev\Workspaces\Nax\Github\node-test\build\test.vcxproj]
```

Comment: i think a problem could be coz of compile order. coz c-file isnt compiled before header-file and cpp file of header file. (only over node-gyp) - is it possible to define compile order with node-gyp?

Comment: What about adding code example demomstrating ths issue?

Comment: added example so maybe it helps

Comment: Uploaded my problem (with real scenario) to github -> https://github.com/NaxChefkoch/node-opc